# Using Flask-Script shell with BPython can't get app context

Tags: python, shell, flask, ipython, bpython

I am building a Flask application using app factory pattern. If I install BPython on my virtualenv, and use the shell, it seems like it cannot get the app context, and therefore when I try to do something like:

```
>> Role.query.all()
```

I get a RuntimeError:

```
application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context
```

I have to use create the app context and do it like this:

```
with app.app_context():
    ...
    do stuff
```

However, if I use IPython, it works fine. In the docs it says it's ready for both BPython and IPython so I don't know why it's not creating the app context.

Answer (score 0):

I reported [this issue](https://github.com/smurfix/flask-script/issues/155). It was a problem with BPython https://github.com/smurfix/flask-script/pull/165